# Advice with JavaScript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write an regular expression where:

1. Starts with letters only
2. Contains only letters and numbers
3. No more than 32 characters in length

what I have so far is:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0,31]+$
```

but I'm not sure if this would be correct.

Comment: Use `{}` symbols to specify the number of occurrences of a character class.

Comment: This site is awesome for learning more about regex.  I recently discovered capturing, which I love.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,31}$/i
```

- `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string.
- `[a-z]` matches a letter.
- `[a-z0-9]{,31}` matches up to 31 letters and numbers.
- `i` makes your regex case-insensitive.

Comment: You can also use `{31,}` to represent "_31 or more_".

Comment: thanks for the help, I am sure your expression is correct. but I tried your expression but no luck, here's what I did. I went to http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and paste in your expression. it kept telling me "No Match" even when I enter TestString19ABC. Am I missing something?

Comment: also, I would like it to have case in-sensitive, so the expression would be: /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,31}$/i
what I did is:
var expression = new RegExp('/^[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,31}$/i');
if (expression.test('TestString123'))
{ // successful
}

Comment: should be using var expression = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,31}$/i; instead of new RegExp object. thanks!

Comment: @Jim: If you are passing the `i` flag, you don't need to write `a-zA-Z`. `a-z` already matches both.